# The difference between an Android emulator and a physical Android device without GPU

Tags: android, swiftshader

I need to use the CPU to simulate the GPU, implementing the interface call of OpenGL ES.
I learned that both Mesa3D and SwiftShader can be implemented. However, I found out that SwiftShader can be used in the Android emulator, but it does not work on the physical android device without GPU.
Why is it possible to choose GPU software simulation (Mesa, SwiftShader) on the Android emulator, but not on the physical android device without GPU?
So, what is the difference between an Android emulator and a physical android device without GPU?
Can you give me some suggestion?

Comment: This conversation between swiftshader developers would indeed help you or guide you in finding your answer. https://groups.google.com/g/swiftshader/c/9Rq6hbgskTM

Comment: Thanks very much for your help ! But i have seen this and still have questions in the difference .

Comment: `but it does not work on the physical android device without GPU` how did you manage to know that fact, did you test, or somebody told you?